# Android Inside custom dialog :- How to open DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog

Please can anyone help me regarding how i can open Date Picker Dialog if i want to open it from a custom Dialog, i Have a custom dialog class like below

```
public class ReceiptsDialog extends CustomActivity {
    private static ReceiptsDialog instance;
    private static Activity mContext;
    private static Dialog customDialog;
    static EditText tv_date;

    public static ReceiptsDialog getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ReceiptsDialog();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void createDialog(Activity mContext,Dialogclick dialogclick) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.dialogclick = dialogclick;
        customDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.receipts_dialog);
        customDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        customDialog.show();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        tv_date = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_date);
        setTouchNClick(tv_date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);

        if (v == tv_date) {
            DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            dFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyCalTheme, this, year, month, day);
            return dpd;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            final SimpleDateFormat dateViewFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);//hh:mm:ss
            Calendar choosen = Calendar.getInstance();
            choosen.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            tv_date.setText(dateViewFormatter.format(choosen.getTime()));
        }
    }
}
```

i want to open Date picker Dialog on Click of tv_date

but this is giving error :

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>    Activity has been destroyed at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl. enqueueAction (FragmentManager.java:2114) at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.
>
> commit (BackStackRecord.java:637)
>           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:144)
>           at com.omegasoftware.olivepos.home.functions.ReceiptsDialog.onClick(ReceiptsDialog.java:141)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21164)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)

Comment: first of all **you should not use operator new with Activity derived class**, second: **you should not use static with any class which is connected to activity Context**

Comment: `ReceiptsDialog` is not being used as an `Activity`, and it should not extend any `Activity` class. Remove `extends CustomActivity` from the class declaration, and you will see which method call is causing your issue.

Comment: @Mike M. if i will not extend it with activity   
    # Fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");#

this line will cause error getSupportFragmentManager/getFragmentManager not available 
what i should use here in this case?

Comment: Well, you're passing an `Activity` into `createDialog()`, so, technically, you could use that, provided it's an `AppCompatActivity`, and you cast it as such first, or change the parameter and field type to `AppCompatActivity`. However, your setup is a little atypical. You're first showing a regular `Dialog`, but then showing a `DialogFragment` from that?

Comment: really its typical, "AppCompatActivity" not acceptable can you solve this for me

Comment: If you can't somehow get an `AppCompatActivity` there, then you can't get a support `FragmentManager`. That's just how it is.

Comment: Thanks @Selvin  'static'  instance was creating problem, now it solved after your suggestion of removing all static. extending with activity is not any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Working Solution*
**Regular Dialog** opening **Date Picker** : *use below example*

```
public class ReceiptsDialog extends CustomActivity {
    private Activity mContext;
    private Dialog customDialog;
    EditText tv_date;

    public void createDialog(Activity mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        customDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.receipts_dialog);
        customDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        customDialog.show();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        tv_date = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_date);
        setTouchNClick(tv_date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
        if (v == tv_date) {
            View vv = v;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(mContext,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String s = dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                            tv_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                        }
                    }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
            dpd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to rotate the screen while dialog is shown? ... This is **Working in some case solution** but should not be used in production code .... also as @MikeM. wrote ... therer is no need to `extends CustomActivity` here

Comment: i need this extend because i have lot of work in this dialog, making for tablet, only for landscape mode. it is same like a activity work but should look like dialog, so i am using it  otherwise i remove it